# Calculations for every unique/distinct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, vba

I have a very large data set that I need to work with and in my calculations three columns are of interest. Let's call the different columns [A], [B] and [C]. In [A] I have a list of different company names, where each company name might occur several times. I have created a table for the data and sorted the company names alphabetically. Let's say I have the company name X in A2:A5 and the calculation that needs to be done is SUMPRODUCT(B2:B5;C2:C5)/SUM(C2:C5). How do I calculate this for every unique/distinct company name and present the result in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula in a new column D for example in D2:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$10=A2)*$B$2:$B$10*$C$2:$C$10)/SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,A2,$C$2:$C$10),"")
```

and drag it down whenever the value in A changes it will write a result

Change A2:A10, B2:B10 and C2:C10 to correspond your last row and keep $ for fixed references
To correspond to your settings I wrote ";" in the following:

```
=IF(A2<>A1;SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$10=A2)*$B$2:$B$10*$C$2:$C$10)/SUMIF($A$2:$A$10;A2;$C$2:$C$10);"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Put two INDEX functions together with a `:` for the range.

```
=IF(A2<>A3, SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(A2, A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(A2&"z", A:A)), INDEX(C:C, MATCH(A2, A:A, 0)):INDEX(C:C, MATCH(A2&"z", A:A)))/SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, A2), TEXT(,))
```

The first occurrence is found with,

```
INDEX(B:B, MATCH(A2, A:A, 0))
```

The last  occurrence (on sorted data) is found with,

```
INDEX(B:B, MATCH(A2&"z", A:A))
```

[image]

Note that I changed your SUM to a SUMIFS to make life a little easier.